# Adding Columns using Power Queries in excel that copy the first row of the next column

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, m

I'm looking to create new columns to the left of columns 3 through 42 that simply copy the first value from the column to their right. In the picture, then, I'm looking for a column next to Column3 which just has "Auto" for every entry and then one to the left of Column4 that is full of "Home" and so on and so forth.
[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI5sc.png)

I got help to create queries that copy the value from Column3, "Auto", and then create a new column at the end of my data with that value, but I'm sure there's a way to make a loop that could simultaneously do this for every one of my columns (3-42) and maybe even put the columns where they're supposed to go (to the left of their matching column). Here is a photo of the queries I have thusfar:
[current queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78smF.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm just learning how to use Power Query! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work okay if you remove your existing

```
in
#"Added Custom"
```

and append this to your code in home ... advanced editor

```
First2Cols = List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom"),2),
AdditionalCols = List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom"),2),
TopRow = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.FirstN(#"Added Custom",1),First2Cols),
NewNames=List.Transform(AdditionalCols , each  _ & "_"),
CombineTables = TopRow & Table.RenameColumns( #"Added Custom" , List.Zip( { AdditionalCols, NewNames} ) ),
#"Filled Down" = Table.Skip(Table.FillDown(CombineTables,AdditionalCols),1),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filled Down", First2Cols & List.Sort( NewNames & AdditionalCols) )
in  #"Reordered Columns"
```

you should then probably promote the first row to headers

Comment: I appreciate the help so much. That was clever! For some reason, I'm getting an error that says:                                                                                                                                                 "Expression.Error: The column 'Column1' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Column1"                                                                                                                                               for the Top Row step: = Table.RemoveColumns(Table.FirstN(Source,1),First2Cols)                                 Any idea why?

Comment: see if this works better. I changed above code. I kept referencing source instead #"Added Custom"

Comment: It worked! That makes sense. I appreciate the help very much, and I can use this to learn more about M as well. You're the best.

Comment: Please accept the answer then. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.